# Building shared libraries with Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a project that I want to build a shared library for it. The following Makefile works:

```
libfastpd.so: fastpd.cpp
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 -fPIC -c fastpd.cpp -o fastpd.o
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 -fPIC -c graph.cpp -o graph.o
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 -fPIC -c LinkedBlockList.cpp -o LinkedBlockList.o
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 -fPIC -c maxflow.cpp -o maxflow.o
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 -shared  -Wl,-soname,libfastpd.so -o libfastpd.so fastpd.o graph.o LinkedBlockList.o maxflow.o

clean:
    rm *.o *.so
```

Then I came across this recipe in Cogswell et al.'s C++ Cookbook: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596007612/ch01s18.html
and decided to improve my Makefile based on that:

```
# Specify extensions of files to delete when cleaning
CLEANEXTS   = o so

# Specify the source files, the target files, 
# and the install directory 
SOURCES  = fastpd.cpp graph.cpp LinkedBlockList.cpp maxflow.cpp
OUTPUTFILE  = libfastpd.so
INSTALLDIR  = ./


.PHONY: all
all: $(OUTPUTFILE)

# Build lib*.so from all the *.o;
# subst is the search-and-replace 
# function demonstrated in Recipe 1.16
$(OUTPUTFILE): $(subst .cpp,.o,$(SOURCES)) 
    $(CXX) -shared -fPIC $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

.PHONY: install
install:
    mkdir -p $(INSTALLDIR)
    cp -p $(OUTPUTFILE) $(INSTALLDIR)

.PHONY: clean 
clean:
    for file in $(CLEANEXTS); do rm -f *.$$file; done

# Generate dependencies of .ccp files on .hpp files
include $(subst .cpp,.d,$(SOURCES))

%.d: %.cpp
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
rm -f $@.$$$$
```

Running this file I obtained the following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: fastpd.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can
>   not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   fastpd.o: error adding symbols: Bad value

Checking the terminal output, I observed that the following commands were executed:

```
g++    -c -o fastpd.o fastpd.cpp
g++    -c -o graph.o graph.cpp
g++    -c -o LinkedBlockList.o LinkedBlockList.cpp
g++    -c -o maxflow.o maxflow.cpp
```

No `-fPIC`!

My question is: *Which lines of the Makefile execute these commands and how to add `-fPIC` to them?*

Any references to good ressources to understand the entire Makefile above would be very much appreciated as well!

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not use CMake?

Comment: @Nestor or more importantly....why use CMake, or why not use scons (puke....)     : ))

Comment: @Nestor @code_fodder For this small project I found that `make` is simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which lines of the Makefile execute these commands... ?

The short answer is *none*.  The rule...

```
$(OUTPUTFILE): $(subst .cpp,.o,$(SOURCES)) 
        $(CXX) -shared -fPIC $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

only specifies the link time dependencies and command.  The `-fPIC` option needs to be specified when you compile the source file  but you haven't provided any rule to build a `.o` from a `.cpp` so `make` falls back on its [implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) which (for the purposes of this example) is essentially...

```
%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

So the obvious solution is to add `-fPIC` to `CXXFLAGS`...

```
CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks a lot!